# How to make hierarchy structure for menuplating a field of documents by multiple users in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firestore. I have a list of items(documents) in a collection C1. there is a button like to select your favorite item and if a user makes item favorite or not favorite then it should show only to himself, not to all other users.

I am making an array of strings as a field of the document for "like"  where I am putting the ids of users who are liking the items if a user dislikes it I remove the id of users. Every time I have to fetch all data and like string, array to check whether my id is there or not but this is really lazy logic as records increase it will be stuck,

I can not perform the long operation in mobile, for example, there may be 50k size of "Like" array, I can't search my id from 50k and then goes to next item and then again finding id. so how I can achieve like this

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection("puppies")
        .where('puppy_fav', isEqualTo: true).where('puppy_owner_email', isEqualTo: emailOwner)
        .snapshots();
```

there should some operation on firestore it should return me only yes on not against my id.

[image: List of items with like button]

[image: firestore]

Comment: Why can't you search each like array for the ID? Seems fine at low volume of users/likes.

Comment: @DanFein what would be if I have more than 1000 documents and in each document "Like" array has 50k length. when I will render my list in mobile I have to search my required id from 50k and then I will render the next item of list which will again search from that array.  So it will be a really lazy response from the firebase.

Comment: Why do you say "is really lazy logic as records increase it will be stuck"? Why do you think it will be stuck?

Comment: I totally respect building for scale, but wondering if you're building for an unlikely issue. How frequently do you think the same puppy will have 1,000 people liking it? Even 100 people liking it? Even 10 people liking it? If you go to the average Instagram pics, I bet you rarely find more than 25 likes. Of course there are alternative structures but do think it's worth considering the pros and cons of the structure you already have.

Comment: @DanFein I got you, but I am not talking about the importance of the app or puppies, but want to know how two things can join 1) my private liking 2) general public list, one solution can be that we copy the general public list (all puppies list)into user profile, in this way we does not need to worry about managing 2 different things but that is not a good solution it will increase the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo time complexity is increasing that is why i say it will stuck. suppose "fav" array has 50k email addresses, now when I fetch the data ,my mobile will be out of memory because my data-structure will try to contain that memory from storage but it will not find it.